# error when decoding:ANSI caracter â€

Tags: python, python-3.x, encoding

i have a program in python 3 that read and compare files (that have the same name) in tow folder "gold" and "predcition"

but generate this error, my file are in UTF8 format so the caracter that generate the error is XE2 X80 (in ANSI it is â€) :

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\scienceie2017_train\test.py", line 215, in <module>
    calculateMeasures(folder_gold, folder_pred, remove_anno)
  File "C:\scienceie2017_train\test.py", line 34, in calculateMeasures
    res_full_pred, res_pred, spans_pred, rels_pred = normaliseAnnotations(f_pred, remove_anno)
  File "C:\scienceie2017_train\test.py", line 132, in normaliseAnnotations
    for l in file_anno:
  File "C:\Users\chedi\Anaconda3\lib\codecs.py", line 321, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode bytes in position 915-916: invalid continuation byte
```

the code is:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# by Mattew Peters, who spotted that sklearn does macro averaging not
# micro averaging correctly and changed it

import os
from sklearn.metrics import precision_recall_fscore_support
import sys


def calculateMeasures(folder_gold="data/dev/", folder_pred="data_pred/dev/", remove_anno=""):
    '''
    Calculate P, R, F1, Macro F
    :param folder_gold: folder containing gold standard .ann files
    :param folder_pred: folder containing prediction .ann files
    :param remove_anno: if set if "rel", relations will be ignored. Use this setting to only evaluate
    keyphrase boundary recognition and keyphrase classification. If set to "types", only keyphrase boundary recognition is evaluated.
    Note that for the later, false positive
    :return:
    '''

    flist_gold = os.listdir(folder_gold)
    res_all_gold = []
    res_all_pred = []
    targets = []

    for f in flist_gold:
        # ignoring non-.ann files, should there
        # be any
        if not str(f).endswith(".ann"):
            continue
        f_gold = open(os.path.join(folder_gold, f), "r", encoding="utf")
        try:
            f_pred = open(os.path.join(folder_pred, f), "r", encoding="utf8")
            res_full_pred, res_pred, spans_pred, rels_pred = normaliseAnnotations(f_pred, remove_anno)
        except IOError:
            print(f + " file missing in " + folder_pred + ". Assuming no predictions are available for this file.")
            res_full_pred, res_pred, spans_pred, rels_pred = [], [], [], []

        res_full_gold, res_gold, spans_gold, rels_gold = normaliseAnnotations(f_gold, remove_anno)

        spans_all = set(spans_gold + spans_pred)

        for i, r in enumerate(spans_all):
            if r in spans_gold:
                target = res_gold[spans_gold.index(r)].split(" ")[0]
                res_all_gold.append(target)
                if not target in targets:
                    targets.append(target)
            else:

                res_all_gold.append("NONE")

            if r in spans_pred:
                target_pred = res_pred[spans_pred.index(r)].split(" ")[0]
                res_all_pred.append(target_pred)
            else:

                res_all_pred.append("NONE")

        #y_true, y_pred, labels, targets
        prec, recall, f1, support = precision_recall_fscore_support(res_all_gold, res_all_pred, labels=targets, average=None)
        metrics = {}
        for k, target in enumerate(targets):
            metrics[target] = {
                'precision': prec[k],
                'recall': recall[k],
                'f1-score': f1[k],
                'support': support[k]
            }

        # now
        # micro-averaged
        if remove_anno != 'types':
            prec, recall, f1, s = precision_recall_fscore_support(res_all_gold, res_all_pred, labels=targets, average='micro')
            metrics['overall'] = {
                'precision': prec,
                'recall': recall,
                'f1-score': f1,
                'support': sum(support)
            }
        else:
            # just
            # binary
            # classification,
            # nothing
            # to
            # average
            metrics['overall'] = metrics['KEYPHRASE-NOTYPES']

    print_report(metrics, targets)
    return metrics

def print_report(metrics, targets, digits=2):
    def _get_line(results, target, columns):
        line = [target]
        for column in columns[:-1]:
            line.append("{0:0.{1}f}".format(results[column], digits))
        line.append("%s" % results[columns[-1]])
        return line

    columns = ['precision', 'recall', 'f1-score', 'support']

    fmt = '%11s' + '%9s' * 4 + '\n'
    report = [fmt % tuple([''] + columns)]
    report.append('\n')
    for target in targets:
        results = metrics[target]
        line = _get_line(results, target, columns)
        report.append(fmt % tuple(line))
    report.append('\n')

    # overall
    line = _get_line(
    metrics['overall'], 'avg / total', columns)
    report.append(fmt % tuple(line))
    report.append('\n')

    print(''.join(report))

def normaliseAnnotations(file_anno, remove_anno):
    '''
    Parse annotations from the annotation files: remove relations (if requested), convert rel IDs to entity spans
    :param file_anno:
    :param remove_anno:
    :return:
    '''
    res_full_anno = []
    res_anno = []
    spans_anno = []
    rels_anno = []

    for l in file_anno:
        print(l)
        print(l.strip('\n'))
        r_g = l.strip('\n').split("\t")
        print(r_g)
        print(len(r_g))
        r_g_offs = r_g[1].split()
        print(r_g_offs)
        if remove_anno != "" and r_g_offs[0].endswith("-of"):
            continue

        res_full_anno.append(l.strip())

        if r_g_offs[0].endswith("-of"):
            arg1 = r_g_offs[1].replace("Arg1:", "")
            arg2 = r_g_offs[2].replace("Arg2:", "")
            for l in res_full_anno:
                r_g_tmp = l.strip().split("\t")
                if r_g_tmp[0] == arg1:
                    ent1 = r_g_tmp[1].replace(" ", "_")
                if r_g_tmp[0] == arg2:
                    ent2 = r_g_tmp[1].replace(" ", "_")

            spans_anno.append(" ".join([ent1, ent2]))
            res_anno.append(" ".join([r_g_offs[0], ent1, ent2]))
            rels_anno.append(" ".join([r_g_offs[0], ent1, ent2]))

        else:
            spans_anno.append(" ".join([r_g_offs[1], r_g_offs[2]]))
            keytype = r_g[1]
            if remove_anno == "types":
                keytype = "KEYPHRASE-NOTYPES"
            res_anno.append(keytype)

    for r in rels_anno:
        r_offs = r.split(" ")
# reorder hyponyms to start with smallest index
# 1, 2
        if r_offs[0] == "Synonym-of" and r_offs[2].split("_")[1] < r_offs[1].split("_")[1]:
            r = " ".join([r_offs[0], r_offs[2], r_offs[1]])
        if r_offs[0] == "Synonym-of":
            for r2 in rels_anno:
                r2_offs = r2.split(" ")
                if r2_offs[0] == "Hyponym-of" and r_offs[1] == r2_offs[1]:
                    r_new = " ".join([r2_offs[0], r_offs[2], r2_offs[2]])
                    rels_anno[rels_anno.index(r2)] = r_new

                if r2_offs[0] == "Hyponym-of" and r_offs[1] == r2_offs[2]:
                    r_new = " ".join([r2_offs[0], r2_offs[1], r_offs[2]])
                    rels_anno[rels_anno.index(r2)] = r_new

    rels_anno = list(set(rels_anno))

    res_full_anno_new = []
    res_anno_new = []
    spans_anno_new = []

    for r in res_full_anno:
        r_g = r.strip().split("\t")
        if r_g[0].startswith("R") or r_g[0] == "*":
            continue
        ind = res_full_anno.index(r)
        res_full_anno_new.append(r)
        res_anno_new.append(res_anno[ind])
        spans_anno_new.append(spans_anno[ind])

    for r in rels_anno:
        res_full_anno_new.append("R\t" + r)
        res_anno_new.append(r)
        spans_anno_new.append(" ".join([r.split(" ")[1], r.split(" ")[2]]))

    return res_full_anno_new, res_anno_new, spans_anno_new, rels_anno

if __name__ == '__main__':
    folder_gold = "data/dev/"
    folder_pred = "data_pred/dev/"
    remove_anno = ""  # "", "rel" or "types"
    if len(sys.argv) >= 2:
        folder_gold = sys.argv[1]
    if len(sys.argv) >= 3:
        folder_pred = sys.argv[2]
    if len(sys.argv) == 4:
        remove_anno = sys.argv[3]

    calculateMeasures(folder_gold, folder_pred, remove_anno)
```

example of prediction file

```
T1  Task 4 20   particular phase
T2  Task 4 26   particular phase field
T3  Task 15 26  phase field
T4  Task 15 32  phase field model
T5  Task 21 32  field model
T6  Task 93 118 dimensional thermal phase
T7  Task 105 118    thermal phase
T8  Task 105 124    thermal phase field
T9  Task 15 26  phase field
T10 Task 15 32  phase field model
T11 Task 21 32  field model
T12 Task 146 179    dimensional thermal-solutal phase
T13 Task 158 179    thermal-solutal phase
T14 Task 158 185    thermal-solutal phase field
T15 Task 15 26  phase field
T16 Task 15 32  phase field model
T17 Task 21 32  field model
T18 Task 219 235    physical problem
T19 Task 300 330    natural relaxational phenomena
T20 Task 308 330    relaxational phenomena
T21 Task 340 354    resulting PDEs
T22 Task 362 374    Allenâ€“Cahn
T23 Task 383 403    Carnâ€“Hilliard type
T24 Task 445 461    time derivatives
T25 Task 509 532    variational derivatives
T26 Task 541 554    functional â€
T27 Task 570 581    free energy
T28 Task 570 592    free energy functional
T29 Task 575 592    energy functional
T30 Task 570 581    free energy
T31 Task 702 717    domain boundary
T32 Task 780 797    difficult aspects
T33 Task 817 836    relaxational aspect
T34 Task 874 898    stable numerical schemes
T35 Task 881 898    numerical schemes
```

example of gold file

```
T1  Material 2 20   fluctuating vacuum
T2  Process 45 59   quantum fields
T3  Task 45 59  quantum fields
T4  Process 74 92   free Maxwell field
T5  Process 135 151 Fermionic fields
T6  Process 195 222 undergo vacuum fluctuations
T7  Process 257 272 Casimir effects
T8  Task 396 411    nuclear physics
T9  Task 434 464    “MIT bag model” of the nucleon
T10 Task 518 577    a collection of fermionic fields describing confined quarks
T11 Process 732 804 the bag boundary condition modifies the vacuum fluctuations of the field
T12 Task 983 998    nuclear physics
T13 Material 1063 1080  bag-model nucleon
T14 Material 507 514    nucleon
T15 Task 843 856    Casimir force
T16 Process 289 300 such fields
```

Comment: â€ is not an ANSI character.

Comment: i notepade when i change to ansi it is â€ , when i change to UTF8 it is XE2 X80

Answer (score 0):

`"â€“".encode("cp1256").decode("utf8")` = `–`, an en dash.

The file you are opening appears to be encoded in UTF-8 and you are not specifying the encoding that should be used when `open()`ing them (just add `encoding="utf8"` to the parameters).

Python will use the operating system's default character encoding and you appear to be using Windows, where it's always something other than UTF-8. Take a look at

```
import locale
locale.getpreferredencoding()
```

to find out what encoding Python will use by default when reading and writing files.

Comment: sorry i forget ti make the change in the code,  i also used encoding="utf8", but the solution that i find is to use latin encoding="latin-1" ! where i can add the encode decode instruction?

Comment: You don't need to add the encode-decode snippet anywhere, I just wanted to show where that possible character sequence came from (that is, you get `â€“` by encoding a dash character in UTF-8 and decoding it as `cp1256`).